# Substring of a DateTime with Linq to Sql extensions

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to get a list of dates from my table, which contains a number of DateTime values in a column called StartTime.  My predecessor was using the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), StartTime, 120), 1, 10)
```

This results in a distinct list of dates in "yyyy-MM-dd" format for each row in the table.  I'm trying to convert this to Linq-to-SQL by doing the following:

```
query.Select(o => o.StartTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).Distinct()
```

However this results in an error "Method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL."

How can I do this Substring/Convert using Linq-to-SQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of relying on string processing, you can handle this via [DateTime properties supported in LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882657.aspx):

```
var results = query.Select(o => o.StartTime.Date).Distinct();
```

If you want to view this as a string, later, you can use LINQ to Objects to convert the results:

```
var stringResults = results.AsEnumerable().Select(d => d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do:

```
query.Select(o => o.StartTime.Date)
     .Distinct() // Runs on the database
     .AsEnumerable() // Convert to local sequence
     .Select(date => date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")) // Runs on the client
```

The `DateTime.Date` property (strips the sub-date portion out) is supported in LINQ to SQL, so everything other than the date-formatting will run on the database.

Comment: That would be distinct on the full date-time value, not on the date portion.

Comment: @Jon: No, it would be distinct on the Date portion alone. Note the mapping to DateTime.Date on the Select clause.